# Redirect or alter specific registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE based on the logged in user

Tags: windows, remote-desktop-services, windows-registry

We would like to run an application under Terminal Server that's typically designed to run on a single client machine connected via network to a local server. This will mean multiple users logged on to one terminal server where based on the application's design it's really expecting one user sitting on one desktop PC.

As part of this, there are some settings under a specific key for the application under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\{ApplicationName} that we want to make per-user. Is there a way (via Group Policy or any other mechanism) to either redirect the entire key to another location based on the logged in user, or alternatively to force specific entries to be returned for a given user.

Unfortunately all the answers/tutorials I've been able to find focus on adjusting the key via script on logon so aren't really workable for our use case because multiple users will be signed on to a Terminal Server. Is it something that can somehow be adjusted per-user with multiple users signed in at the same time?

Comment: AFAIK neither is possible. The only way I can think of would be to virtualize the application for every user.

Comment: Can you please give me a bit more information about what you mean by virtualise for every user?

Comment: You take a solution that [virtualizes single applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization) (google it, we don't provide product recommendations here) and create a dedicated virtualized instance for each user.